# Activity is not starting up and also no error shown

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm very new to android and I'm facing a wired problem.

I'm starting an activity like this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),InvoiceActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("invoice",extras.getString("invoice"));
startActivity(i);
```

and in log I can see this line:

```
Starting: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.simplepay.hellomobile/.InvoiceActivity (has extras) } from pid 4785
```

but in my emulator and also in my android device the activity is not starting at all. No exception too.

Where will be the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry that is an mistake. I'm calling `startActivity(i);`

Comment: is this already answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not added **startActivity**: Add this: `startActivity(i);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,InvoiceActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("invoice",extras.getString("invoice"));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,InvoiceActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("invoice",extras.getString("invoice"));
startActivity(i);
```

the above code will run but before running this it is highly recommended for you to learn the basics of android. To start another activity from one activity Here is an nice example in android developer site [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem I think is that you are using the context of the entire application. Use the context of the current activity instead.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this,InvoiceActivity.class);
 i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 i.putExtra("invoice",extras.getString("invoice"));
 startActivity(i);
```

Or you can do this way.

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this,InvoiceActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("invoice",extras.getString("invoice"));
startActivity(i);
```